# I need the list of parameter to the iHotelier stytem that can be passs in the url

Tags: url, parameters

I currently developing an hotel web site and they use the iHotelier system. I found what are some of the valid parameter thant can be pass in the url, but i still need help with the departure and arrival date.

Do anybody have an idea of what those parameters are.

Note: An exemple of an hotel using this system is the Gouveneur Hotel in Quebec (https://booking.ihotelier.com/istay/istay.jsp?hotelid=12591&rateplanid=136342&languageID=3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the parameters you can pass to iHotelier on the URL:

URL Parameters:

referID, 
rateplanID, 
hotelID, 
dateIN, 
nights, 
length (means the same as nights), 
dateout, 
rooms, 
adults, 
children, 
packageID, 
prodID (means the same as packageID), 
packageCategoryID, 
identifier, 
roomtypeID, 
languageID, 
confirmid, 
groupID.

Augie Saldate